# Flutter - redraw only part of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

First of all, I need some advice (hopefully I can do it myself). So I have an application as shown in the picture below. It works, but my problem is that it redraws the whole screen every 30 milliseconds (that's how long I set the timer and call setState to show the clock and counter movement).

[image: MainScreen]

Now it's all one StatefulWidget. What and how do I change it so that only the widgets framed in blue and red (either separately or simultaneously) are updated, and not the whole screen. The one framed in yellow should only refresh/redraw when I press either button. I hope I made myself clear.

**UPDATE** → @pskink

I tried the ListenableBuilder on a test app, and it seems working.

```
class DigitalSW with ChangeNotifier {
  Timer? timer;
  Stopwatch stopwatch = clock.stopwatch();
  bool _started = false;
  bool get started => _started;
  int _milli = 0;
  int get milli => _milli;

  void toggleStartStop() {
    if (_started) {
      // stop
      stopwatch.stop();
      _started = false;
      timer!.cancel();
      timer = null;
    } else {
      // start
      stopwatch.start();
      _milli = stopwatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds;
      _started = true;
      timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 30), (timer) {
        notifyListeners();
      });
    }
  }

  void resetSW() {
    stopwatch.reset();
    _milli = 0;
  }

  String returnFormattedText() {
    var milli = stopwatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds;

    String milliseconds = (milli % 1000).toString().padLeft(3, '0');
    String seconds = ((milli ~/ 1000) % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String minutes = ((milli ~/ 1000) ~/ 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    return '$minutes:$seconds:$milliseconds';
  }
}

class _SWPageState extends State<SWPage> {
  final DigitalSW digitalSW = DigitalSW();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ListenableBuilder(
              listenable: digitalSW,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                return Text(digitalSW.returnFormattedText());
              },
            ),
            digitalSW.started
                ? const Text('... RUNNING')
                : const Text('NOT RUNNING'),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  key: const Key('btnStartStop'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      digitalSW.toggleStartStop();
                    });
                  },
                  child: digitalSW.started
                      ? const Text('Stop')
                      : const Text('Start'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  key: const Key('btnReset'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      digitalSW.resetSW();
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Reset'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The only problem that "widget inspector" marks incorrectly.
Why doesn't the widget inspector only show the text in red as an item to be updated?
[image: MainScreen]

Comment: are "widgets framed in blue and red" `CustomPaint` widgets?

Comment: Only the analog clock / watch. The digital is simple Text.

Comment: I'd avoid calling setState on the whole widget if only some parts of it need to updated. Either way there is the [RepaintBoundary widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RepaintBoundary-class.html) you can wrap those parts in.

Comment: so check `ListenableBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder` for a red part and `repaint` parameter of `CustomPainter` constructor for a blue part

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit – I've tried this RepaintBoundary, but either it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong. I'll give it another try anyway.

Comment: @pskink – Thanks! I will look/read up on these ...

Comment: @pskink pls. check my updated question / comment.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean... btw you don't need a custom `ChangeNotifier` you can use `ValueNotifier` instead (but it is really not important that much)

Comment: @pskink – My problem is that it shows the re-paint outside, around (light green), as opposed to what I would expect to see just around the text (counter). So in principle the code is good (do you think so?), but I don't see what I expected.

Comment: yes, the code is good: the only widget that is rebuilt is a `Text` inside `ListenableBuilder` - but I am not familiar with those green frames in widget inspector

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your code looks like, but what I would do would be separate the blue and red widgets and apply the logic that you have set in the Stateful Widget and let the yellow widget to be Stateless (because it will never suffer modifications/changes). I hope it is clear for you.